# How to set all content in a <div> to a blank target (target="_blank")

Tags: javascript, html, css, target

I need to set all of the content in a certain `<div>` to open to another tab (    `target="_blank"`).
I don't really care how this is solved, you can use JS, CSS, HTML, classes, IDs, et cetera.

I tried using     `<base target="_blank">` but it covered everything no matter what rather than just a certain area.
Example:
`<a href="example.html"> <div> <base target="_blank"> [CONTENT] </div>`
I thought that example.html would be opened in the same tab, but its target is set to `"_blank"` as well.

I also tried doing     `<div target="_blank">` but it didn't make any effect, instead it was treated as a normal     `<div>`.

Comment: Do you mean that if the user clicks on the `<div>` then it should open a new tab, or what?

Comment: I want all content inside of the     `<div>` to open a new tab, but not the structure itself.

Comment: So all `<a>` elements within get the attribute `target="_blank"`?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a class to the `<div>` elements whose `<a>` element must get `target="_blank"`, then use the CSS selector `.target_blank a` to get all `<a>` elements that are children of an element with that class. From there you can just loop over them and set the `.target` property:

```js
const target_blank = document.querySelectorAll('.target_blank a');
for (const el of target_blank) {
  el.target = "_blank";
}
```

```html
<div class="target_blank">
  <a href="https://example.com" id="test1">Test 1</a>
  <div>
    <a href="https://example.com">Test 2</a>
  </div>
</div>

<a href="https://example.com" id="test3">Test 3</a>
<a href="https://example.com">Test 4</a>
```